# Why $E[X|X=Y]\neq E[Y]$?

Tags: probability, expectation

The full question was:

> Let $X$ be the number of tosses until a coin with probability of $1\over 3$ to land on Heads does and $Y$ the number of tosses until a fair coin lands on Heads. What is $E[X|X=Y]$?

The correct answer is apperently $3\over 2$, which is lower than both $E[X]$ and $E[Y]$. What I'm confused about is if I know that $X=Y$, and I know that $Y=2$, then also $X=2$, therefore

$$E[X|X=Y]=\sum_k k\cdot P(X=k|X=Y) = \sum_k k \cdot P(Y=k) = E[Y]$$

which seems to be wrong, my guess would be because knowing that $X=Y$ also gives us information on $Y$, but I'm still not able to understand how or why it works.

Comment: Why did you write $\sum_kkP(X=k)=\sum_kkP(Y=k)$? The probabilities in the two sums are all different.

Comment: @smcc Yeah I meant the conditional probability, sorry.

Comment: $P(X=k|X=Y)\neq P(Y=k)$  Consider $X$ a random number between $1$ and $4$, and $Y$ a random number between $1$ and $6$.  $P(X=6|X=Y)=0$ but $P(Y=6)=\frac{1}{6}$

Comment: To give a trivial but hopefully illuminating counterexample to the question in the title. Let $X=1$, and let $Y$ be the roll of a fair die. Then $E[Y]=7/2$ and $E[X|X=Y]=1$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen That makes a lot of sense. Will still need to wrap my head around this though..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not exclude that there is a shortcut, but I think this must work:

$\Pr\left(X=k\mid X=Y\right)\Pr\left(X=Y\right)=\Pr\left(X=k\wedge X=Y\right)=\Pr\left(X=k=Y\right)$

So:

$$\mathbb{E}\left(X\mid X=Y\right)\Pr\left(X=Y\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k\Pr\left(X=k\mid X=Y\right)\Pr\left(X=Y\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k\Pr\left(X=k=Y\right)$$

So that:

$$\mathbb{E}\left(X\mid X=Y\right)=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k\Pr\left(X=k=Y\right)}{\Pr\left(X=Y\right)}=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k\Pr\left(X=k=Y\right)}{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\Pr\left(X=k=Y\right)}$$

$X$ and $Y$ are independent so $\Pr\left(X=k=Y\right)=\Pr\left(X=k\right)\Pr\left(Y=k\right)$.

Comment: Definitely seeing it written clearly helps clarify these. Thanks